# Are the Paris's names "City of Light" and "Lutetia" connected?

Tags: etymology, greek, names, toponyms

Paris is called [City of Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Light). I wonder whether this name could come from ancient name of the city Λευκοτεκία (Ptolemy).

Λευκος in Greek means light or white. And τεκ- root means "stone" (cognates include tectonics and architect).

So the city's name possibly meant "white-stone-city". I wonder whether it is connected to [Lutetian Limestone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutetian_Limestone).

Comment: When was this epithet given to Paris? I think it comes from the 19th century when Paris was one of the first cities of the world with streets illuminated by gas lights.

Comment: *tectonics* is a neologism, not cognate. *-eck* means "place" in Germanic (cp *Schwarzenegger*!), similar to *-wik*, *witz*, *nitz*, *bek*, ... So I'd try bracket *leukot-ekja*, if I could.

Comment: @vectory what Germanic has to do with the place which was at the time occupied by mostly Celts?

Answer (score 2):

Lutetia is more probably from Celtic *luHt- "mud".

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is indeed one of the more respected etymologies for Lutetia.

Answer (score 2):

City of lights is modern term i do not think it has any historical reference

> Paris is often referred to as the 'City of Light' (La Ville Lumière), both because of its leading role during the Age of Enlightenment and more literally because Paris was one of the first large European cities to use gas street lighting on a grand scale on its boulevards and monuments. Gas lights were installed on the Place du Carousel, Rue de Rivoli and Place Vendome in **1829**. By **1857**, the Grand boulevards were lit. By the 1860s, the boulevards and streets of Paris were illuminated by 56,000 gas lamps. Since the late 19th century, Paris has also been known as Panam(e) (pronounced [panam]) in French slang.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris#Etymology